# Node / Vite one build for multi environments

Tags: node.js, npm, frontend, vite

I'm using Vite framework to build my frontend application.

I would like to be able to build a version once, let's say 1.0 and then run it in dev env (with dev variables), then in production (with prod variables). As I do with Java apps for example.

This is quite important because I don't want to "build for prod" once my tests in dev are ok, taking the risk of building something slightly different from dev (dependencies, or even commits).

I know that node frontend projects are simply plain JS files once the application is built, so I don't think reading an env variable would be possible.

Any idea ?